# Is the sentence correctly arranged?

Tags: grammar

> The trick you set up **in which** you pretended to be victim will be revealed

I feel that 'in which' should be right after the trick, but where shall I put the words 'you set up'? Is this sentence grammatically right, and Could you give some advice?

Answer (score 1):

> The trick you set up in which you pretended to be victim will be revealed

First, this looks like something somebody is saying, so it's probably informal. In informal English, you can replace **in which** by **where**.

Second, **you set up** probably isn't necessary, because **you pretended** already indicates who is doing it.

Third, you probably need an article (either **the** or **a**) before victim.

Combining these points, you get:

> The trick where you pretended to be a victim will be revealed